# dropdown is not showing state value on page load

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a react component. Below is my code.

```js
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';
import Dropdown from 'react-bootstrap/Dropdown';

class NotesYear extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={drp:'Select Year'};
        alert(this.state.drp);
    };
    onDropdownSelect(eve){
        alert(eve);
    };
    render(){
      return ( <Container>
            <Row>
                <Col sm={2}>
                    <label>Year</label>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <Dropdown onSelect={this.onDropdownSelect}>
                        <Dropdown.Toggle title={this.state.drp}>                            
                        </Dropdown.Toggle>
                        <Dropdown.Menu >
                            <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1">2019</Dropdown.Item>
                            <Dropdown.Item eventKey="2">2018</Dropdown.Item>
                        </Dropdown.Menu>
                    </Dropdown>
                </Col>
            </Row>    
        </Container>)
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <NotesYear/>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

When I run my application, I am expecting it to display dropdown text "SELECT Year" but it is empty.
I am new to ReactJs. Can someone help me to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of title from Dropdown.Toggle and move `{this.state.drp}` in between `<Dropdown.Toggle>` and `</Dropdown.Toggle>` like this...

```
</Dropdown.Toggle>
    {this.state.drp}
</Dropdown.Toggle>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. Can you please tell me what is the reason it doesn't work with title property.

Comment: as far as I can tell `<Dropdown.Toggle>` doesn't have a title attribute. you may be getting it mixed up with `<DropdownButton>` which allows for the title attribute. that's what I got out of the documentation page https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/